# MagicInfo SSL configuration with Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I've set up a new MagicInfo v9 installation, running on Windows Server 2022. Now I need to configure MagicInfo to use an SSL certificate, to avoid the red warning message "Your connection is not private" when accessing MagicInfo web interface.

There's [very limited](https://docs.nomagic.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=30346631) documentation for what I'm trying to do, and I couldn't find anything for using Let's Encrypt with MagicInfo.

Has anyone done this before, or can you point me to any documentation on how to configure Let's Encrypt with MagicInfo so I don't get the message "Your connection is not private" when accessing MagicInfo web interface. Ideally Let's Encrypt should automatically update the certificate, as it normally does.